# Error when trying to multiply a variable?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to multiply a variable to output a weighted value as follows:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data_2017_18.income1_weight = data_2017_18.income1 * data_2017_18.survey_weight
```

I'm receiving the following error message:

TypeError: Object with dtype category cannot perform the numpy op multiply

I've tried to change the data_2017_18.income1 to an integer as follows:

```
int(data_2017_18.income1)
```

But I'm getting this error:

TypeError: cannot convert the series to <class 'int'>

Any suggestions, please?

Many thanks

Comment: maybe try `data_2017_18.income1.astype(int)`

Comment: Thanks. I got this error: ValueError: Cannot convert float NaN to integer

Answer (score 2):

Try [`Series.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html):

```
data_2017_18.income1_weight = data_2017_18.income1.astype(float) * data_2017_18.survey_weight
```

Comment: Thanks, I got the following: 

ValueError: Cannot convert float NaN to integer

Comment: @johnny_birkenhead - Can you try `.astype(float)` ?