# Dealing with NA's when carrying out a mathematical operator in Python/Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to carry out a multiplication on a survey variable (somewhat related to an earlier [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63487363/error-when-trying-to-multiply-a-variable?noredirect=1#comment112264401_63487363)):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

Data_2017_18.income2_weight = Data_2017_18.income2.astype(int) * Data_2017_18.survey_weight
```

However, I'm receiving this error message:

```
ValueError: Cannot convert float NaN to integer
```

The frequency count of the variable that I'm trying to weight is as follows:

```
Data_2017_18.income2.value_counts()

NA    650
2     181
1      62
```

I was trying a workaround to subset the variable so there were no NA's:

```
income2_2017_18 = Data_2017_18[(Data_2017_18.income2 == 1)]
```

However it is subsetting as follows:

```
income2_2017_18.income2.value_counts()

2     0
NA    0
1     0
```

Any idea why it is doing this and any suggestions on how I can address it, please?

Much appreciated.

Comment: Either do `Data_2017_18.income2.astype('Int64')` or `pd.to_numeric(Data_2017_18.income2, errors='coerce')`. I'd favor the latter to make your column a numeric type.

Comment: Try converting the field to int while reading the csv or what source you have.